# What does "GILEAD SCIENCES INC REV NRA W/H ,03/30" mean?

Tags: stocks, dividends, terminology

What does the `GILEAD SCIENCES INC REV NRA W/H ,03/30` mean in my broker's statement?

I mean, the `INC REV NRA W/H ,03/30` part.

Is that a dividend?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are not industry conventions. NRA W/H means Non-Resident Alien Withholding Tax.

REV could mean anything e.g. Revenue, Reversed, Revised.

Ask the broker who designed this description.

Comment: In surprised the definitions aren't included in the broker's statement. I wonder if that's common?

Comment: And (for completeness, since it was asked in the question): "INC" = "Incorporated", part of the company name.